# How can I assign an integer value to a button using React and JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So basically I am practicing React and trying to make simple components communicate with the parent component. I have come to an issue where I can't figure out how to change the value of a button into an integer so I can make simple calulations. I have tried setting the value with parseInt and without it as well, but I can't seen to understand, pressing the "add" button gives me a NaN. Could anyone help me?
This is what I have in my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Input from "./Components/Input"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 10
    }
  }

  number1 = (event) => {
    this.setState({number: event.target.value})

  }

  number2 = (event) => {
    this.setState({number: event.target.value})
    if (this.state.number < 1){
      this.setState({number: 0})
    }

  }

  add = (event) => {
    this.setState({number: this.number+1})

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input  number={this.state.number} 
                number1={this.number1} 
                number2={this.number2}
                add={this.add} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is what I have in Input.js

````
let numberValue1= parseInt("8")
let numberValue2= parseInt("17")

const Input = ({number, number1, number2, add}) =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{number}</h1>
            <button value={numberValue1} onClick={number1}>Add</button>
            <button value={numberValue2} onClick={number2}>Subtract</button>
            <button  onClick={add}>Subtract</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Input;```
````

Comment: What do you think `this.number` is?

Comment: There is no such instance `this.number`, also you have some mistakes like passing `add` function to `substract` button...

Comment: You need to convert `e.target.value` to `Number` like this: `Number(e.target.value)` and also in `number2` function, you should use `setState()` second argument which is a callback because state is asynchronous, 
```number2 = (event) => {
        this.setState({number: Number(event.target.value), () => {
          if(number < 1) {
            this.setState({number: 0})
          }
        })
    }```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is fundamentally a bit strange - you probably shouldn't be assigning values to button elements, as it's doesn't really make sense for them to have one (if I were to ask you "what is this button's value?" what would you think I meant?).

Instead, it makes more sense to pass a function to the button that accepts an argument.

For example:

```js
const ParentComponent = ()=> {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const add = (amount)=> {
    setNumber(number + amount);
  };

  return (
    <MyInput number={number} onAddButtonClicked={add} />
  )
}

const MyInput = ({number, onAddButtonClicked}) => {
  <div>
    <h1>{number}</h1>
    <button onClick={ ()=> onAddButtonClicked(1) }>Add</button>
    <button onClick={ ()=> onAddButtonClicked(-1) }>Subtract</button>
  </div>
}
```